# How to create a dictionary key inside a another dictionary with the previous values of old dictionary key

Tags: python, json, dictionary, scripting

So I am parsing through a json file with many dictionary values and keys. I want to be able to create a new dictionary key value within another dictionary and take all the contents from the old dictionary and put it within the new dictionary.

Here is what the original json file looks like:

```
{"runContext": {"isAdmin": "false", "isSimulated":false, "customerId": "132", "acId": "1445017", "id":"magtest1"}}
```

Here is what the modified json file should look:

```
{"context": {"user":{"id":"magtest1", "isSimulated":false, "customerId":"132", "isAdmin":false "acID": "1445017}}}
```

I had to change the name of `runContext` to context and then after that I essentially need to create a new object called user and store all the previous contents with context and store it within the new object user. I am opening the original json file using its path name however I am having trouble taking the contents from context and putting into a new object called user

Here is the script I wrote:

```
def jsonparse():
    user_path= input("Please enter path name:")
    with open(user_path) as f:
        x = f.read()
    jObject = json.loads(x)
    context = jObject['runContext']
    jObject['context']= jObject.pop('runContext')
    jObject['context']['user'] = {}
    jObject['context']['user'] = context

    print jObject

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jsonparse()
```

My issue is when I try to print it out, it looks like this

```
{"context":{user:{...}
```

It doesn't output out any values for user
Any help on this is appreciated since I'm new to JSON. Thanks!

Comment: where is `context` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your `context` is not defined. It should be:

```
context = jObject.pop('runContext')
jObject['context']['user'] = {}
jObject['context']['user'] = context
```

Comment: I edited the post.  context = jObject['runContext']. It still does not put all the keys and values into user.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def jsonparse():
    user_path= input("Please enter path name:")
    with open(user_path) as f:
        x = f.read()
    jObject = json.loads(x)
    context = jObject.pop('runContext')
    jObject['context'] = {}
    jObject['context']['user'] = context

    print jObject

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jsonparse()
```

Before on `jObject['context']= jObject.pop('runContext')` you had the dictionary that you need in `jObject['context']['user']` in `jObject['context']`.
Now after `context = jObject.pop('runContext')` the `jObject` will be empty(`{}`) and then you will add the keys `jObject['context'] = {}` and the context `jObject['context']['user'] = context`

Hope that helps.